# Generate a random matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, normalization

I'd like to generate a matrix (m rows and n columns) whose entries are independently sampled from a zero-mean distribution, and each row is normalized to unit length. I know the function randn(m,n) of Matlab, but I'm not sure about "zero-mean" distribution and normalization. Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I think "zero-mean" just means that a given distribution has zero mean. Which still allows a continuum of possible distributions. And is the length in 2-norm? You probably need something like `M=rand(m,n)-0.5; M=bsxfun(@rdivide,M,sqrt(sum(M.^2,2)))`. The elements are initially pseudo-random uniform in `[-0.5, 0.5]`, then the rows are normalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
m=3; n=4;
M = randn([m n]);
M = bsxfun(@rdivide, M, sqrt(sum(M.*M,2))) %//divide each element by the magnitude of it's row
```

`randn()` fulfills `zero-mean distribution` as it samples from a standard normal distribution `~N(0,1)`.

By "*each row normalized to unit length*", Im assuming each `row vector in M` needs to be of `unit length`, so we divide each `element` by the `magnitude of its corresponding row vector`.

Comment: thank you, your answer is similar to that of @Andras above (the second step). What's about the first step? why he want's to subtract 0.5 and you don't?

Comment: The requirement I got from a paper so I don't really understand it well.

Comment: @lenhhoxung I did not subtract 0.5 because the `mean of the distribution` from `randn()` is already 0 and thus I believe there is no need to shift it at all.